# How to search between three table in Laravel

Tags: search, laravel-4

Model

```
   public function school(){
        return $this->belongTo('Schools', 'schoolId');
    }
   public function friend(){
        return $this->hasMany('Friends', 'friendId');
    }
```

Controller

```
$users = User::with(['school' => function($q) use ($keyword) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%' );
    }])
    ->with(['friend' => function ($q) use ($keyword){
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%' );
    }])
    ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->get();
```

I would like to do a search function where some one key in keyword, for example Ali, it will seach between school, friend and user table then return me the schools name, friends name and user name that have Ali.

Inside this 3 table only user name has no Ali, but it return me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change schema. Friend, School and other groups should be pivot table for user and group, so then you will find record only in one table